# How can I verify the authenticity of an APK file I downloaded?

Tags: security, apk

The latest update of Google Maps is unavailable in my country, so I downloaded a version by googling for "Google Maps 5.4.0 apk".  I did in fact find it, but now I wonder how I can tell if this is in fact the same version as in the market.

How can I be sure that it hasn't been tampered with? Are apps signed in any way? Is there any way of checking the signatures?

Comment: If you visit, from your mobile, the page: `m.google.com/maps`, does it offer you a download link or something alike?

Comment: @Nicolás: It links to the market, from which I can't download it.

Comment: related [Verify Android apk has not been repackaged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785001/verify-android-apk-has-not-been-repackaged)

Comment: If you have a second app that is "authentic" and comes from the same vendor, you can compare if both apps are signed using the same keys/identity: [Comparing signatures of apks](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208326/2241)

Comment: As long as it's an APK and not an AAB... you can compare the app signature. This just proves that the app has been signed by a developer who generated a key/

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Sidestepping the debate over the legitimacy of installing that app on your phone, the question of verification is one that I've been meaning to understand for a while, and you've prompted me to try to figure out a possible way of verifying who signed an apk.

Android apps are signed in the normal manner of .jar files (.apk is really just a special .jar which is just a special .zip) however it may not be trivial to *trace* the authenticity of the certificates unless you have something known good to compare to.  That's basically what the phone itself does - verifies that something that claims to be from the same party as something already on the phone actually is - the phone doesn't refuse to install things with unknown signers, it can only (object to/clear application data of) apparent forgeries when something new doesn't match something old that it claims to.

You will need to have jarsigner and keytool. I believe these come from the JDK which is a prerequisite to the android SDK rather than the SDK itself.

First you want try to verify the public key contained within the .apk.  Usually this is in META-INF/CERTS.RSA but it can be in another file - unzip -l will tell you.  You want to see what you can find out about it:

```
unzip -p suspect.apk META-INF/CERT.RSA | keytool -printcert
```

That's going to dump out a lot of information about who the signer claims to be.  Some certificates are apparently themselves signed by known parties, but without figuring out how to trace that, I suspect you could do something like this:

```
unzip -p suspect.apk META-INF/CERT.RSA | keytool -printcert | grep MD5
unzip -p knowngood.apk META-INF/CERT.RSA | keytool -printcert | grep MD5
```

If you have a known trusted apk from the same author who used the same certificate.  I'm assuming that the certificates having the same MD5 sum is enough.

Assuming you've decided to trust the certificate, then you can see if it has been used to sign each of the files within the .apk

```
jarsigner -verbose -verify suspect.apk
```

(If there's more than one .RSA file in the archive, you should add the -certs flag to tell you which certificate(s) have been used to sign each file, so you can be sure its the certificate you verified)

Comment: @Chris Stratton Is it possible to copy Google Maps apk off a device ? Then one can check the certs as you said.

Comment: Recent Android Apps often do no longer contain a v1 signature that can be verified with `jarsigner` (only a v2 orand v3 signature). Therefore `apksigner` from Android SDK should be the preferred way to verify a signature of an APK file.

Answer (score 20):

### Verifying an APK signature

The correct way to verify an APK file is to use `apksigner`.

`apksigner` is part of the Android build tools (Andorid SDK), therefore you may find multiple versions installed, one for each build-tools version installed.

One example path within the Android SDK to `apksigner` is:

```
android-sdk/build-tools/30.0.1/apksigner
```

For more details on how to get apksigner see last chapter of this answer.

Execute apksigner this way:

```
apksigner verify --verbose --print-certs "Signal-website-universal-release-4.49.13.apk"

Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): true
Number of signers: 1
Signer #1 certificate DN: CN=Whisper Systems, OU=Research and Development, O=Whisper Systems, L=Pittsburgh, ST=PA, C=US
Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: 29f34e5f27f211b424bc5bf9d67162c0eafba2da35af35c16416fc446276ba26
Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: 45989dc9ad8728c2aa9a82fa55503e34a8879374
Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: d90db364e32fa3a7bda4c290fb65e310
Signer #1 key algorithm: RSA
Signer #1 key size (bits): 1024
Signer #1 public key SHA-256 digest: 75336a3cc9edb64202cd77cd4caa6396a9b5fc3c78c58660313c7098ea248a55
Signer #1 public key SHA-1 digest: b46cbed18d6fbbe42045fdb93f5032c943d80266
Signer #1 public key MD5 digest: 0f9c33bbd45db0218c86ac378067538d
<skipped a lot of warnings>
```

### Estimate the authenticity of the signer certificate

Now you have verified the APK, but you still don't know if you can trust the person/organization who has signed the APK file. This is because on Android APK signatures use by definition self-signed certificates. If you can trust a certificate is therefore a difficult question. The only way is to check the other apps that have been signed using the same certificate.

The only way I know to do so is to use online PlayStore crawling services like androidobservatory.org. It has an API for checking which apps have been signed by the same certificate using the certificate SHA-1 digest:

- SHA-1: https://androidobservatory.org/cert/45989DC9AD8728C2AA9A82FA55503E34A8879374

Edit: apkmirror.com also allows to search for the certificate digest. Just enter the plain SHA-1 or SHA-256 certificate digest (without colons or spaces) in the search field:

- SHA-1: https://www.apkmirror.com/?post_type=app_release&searchtype=app&s=45989DC9AD8728C2AA9A82FA55503E34A8879374
- SHA-256: https://www.apkmirror.com/?post_type=app_release&searchtype=apk&s=29f34e5f27f211b424bc5bf9d67162c0eafba2da35af35c16416fc446276ba26

On this page you can see all the other APK files on Google Play Store that are signed with the same certificate.

### Getting and executing apksigner

Apksigner is a Java tool and Google provides for start-up a batch file `apksigner.bat`(Windows) respectively a shell script `apksigner.sh` (Linux, MacOS).

As mentioned before it is included in each build-tools version of Android SDK. But it is not placed in PATH so you can not simply open a command-prompt or terminal and execute `apksigner`, instead you have to manually provide the full path to `apksigner.bat`/`apksigner.sh`.

If you don't want to install the whole Android SDK (with or without Android Studio) you can directly download build tools and extract and execute apksigner. Links to the all build-tools are provided on [this website](https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/Buildtools) (the provided links go to the original Google download locations).

I prefer apksigner from build-tools v30:

- [build-tools 30.0.1 Linux](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r30.0.1-linux.zip)
- [build-tools 30.0.1 MacOS](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r30.0.1-macosx.zip)
- [build-tools 30.0.1 Windows](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r30.0.1-windows.zip)

You only need the file `lib/apksigner.jar` from the archive. Extract it  and open a shell in the folder. Then execute `java -jar apksigner.jar`.
To execute you need Java 9 or higher (best Java 11 or 17).

Using this direct approach the command to execute apksigner is

```
java -jar apksigner.jar verify --verbose --print-certs "Signal-website-universal-release-4.49.13.apk"
```

Or if you use full path names - replace the `<..>` sections with the appropriate path that works on your OS:

```
<path to java 9+>/java -jar <path to apksigner>/apksigner.jar verify --verbose --print-certs "<absolute or relative path to apk to be verified>"
```

Comment: This is the answer that helped the most, thanks! I used `apksigner` to compare the cert from an app from the same developer I got from the Google App Store and the one I got from ApkMirror

Comment: For anyone looking to NOT download 1 GB of SDK, this is direct the download link to the (current) build tools: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/91936d4ee3ccc839f0addd53c9ebf087b1e39251.build-tools_r30.0.3-windows.zip

Comment: @BorislavIvanov You should mention that your Link is Windows only. besides that there is still the option do download only the Android SDK without Android Studio. Check the section "Command line tools only" here: https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads It contains the SDK manager that allows to download the "Build tools r30" you have linked. In total you end up with about 150MB download.

Comment: @Robert No, the "Command line tools only" files doesn't contain `apksigner`

Comment: @BorislavIvanov ...and neither does Android Studio

Comment: @kerstin92 Android Studio comes with an installation of Android SDK and at least one version of build-tools, so you should have apksigner installed (but not in the path). You have to call it using the full path to `apksigner.bat`/`apksigner.sh` to execute it.

Comment: @Robert No, it's not part of Android Studio, but came with Build Tools v24.0.3 (but was removed again in later version as it seems). And there is no download for older versions of Build Tools on the Android website. I have the impression that people at Google no longer want any outsider to use `apksigner`

Comment: @kerstin92 Just downloaded build tools for API 33 and apksigner.jar is included. So please recheck your installation and make sure you have at least one build tools package of API around 30 installed.

Answer (score 7):

There is (now) an `apksigner` tool in `build-tools` that does what you want. From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner.html):

> Check whether the APK's signatures are expected to be confirmed as valid on all Android platforms that the APK supports:
>
> ```
> apksigner verify [options] app-name.apk
> ```

Comment: Where to download?

Comment: (from official/"trusted" sources)

Answer (score 2):

You can also try uploading the APK to the free [VirusTotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/) virus checker.  It will generate a unique hash for the APK and if others have already uploaded it to test it (very likely) then you will have more of an idea that the APK is valid.

The service will also scan the APK with over 60 virus scanners and let you know if it believes it has similar signatures to viruses already found.

Comment: I wouldn't trust the virus check, as doubt that these anti-virus programs focus on just every Android APK ever distributed. Also, the MD5 will not tell you much, apart from that the same file has been uploaded before.

Comment: @Stan - It scans the bytes in the file for malware bytes. It doesn't have to know every APK ever distributed. Also, it's not an MD5, it's a SHA256 and there is a bit of additional info communicated in that if this is the first time the APK has ever been uploaded then maybe it is something unknown and more possibly malicious.  Also, most valid APKs will probably be there. Why not include this as part of analysis as another tool for use? It can provide just another level of confidence or non-confidence about the package. You don't have to consider it the final word, but considering it more data

Comment: OK I agree it's useful as an additional source, just not the only one.

Answer (score 0):

To compare certificates from a suspect apk file, maybe one idea is to download it's version on the official Play Store on your phone, doing a backup on your computer and go in the backup directory, select the concerned apk file and do the same checks. You can also view the Google certificates by doing the check on a device-default application (like any com.google.android.* apk)

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned this yet, but you don't necessarily need a command terminal to view the certs?  The `apk`'s can generally be opened using `open as zip`, making it's contents parsable:

[image: screenshot 1]

You can generally find the certs listed in `META-INF` > `manifest.mf`:

[image: screenshot 2]