# App not installed error

Tags: installation, apk, signature-error

When i try to install a minecraft apk it tells me app not installed after further digging it shows me this error:

> INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.mojang.minecraftpe signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!

Answer (score 2):

Apps can only be updated if the are signed by the same developer key.

It seems that the currently installed or the apk you are trying to install are not genuine: they are not signed by the same developer key and thus you are getting the error message "signatures do not match".

You can only uninstall the old apk (this deletes all local data) and then install the new APK file if you trust the developer.

But you should ask yourself where you got got the old and the apk file from. So you really trust the person who has published it? Why do the files have different signatures, may be the APK has been modified and malware has been injected into the APK.

See also how to [check if two APKs are signed with the same developer key](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93022/comparing-signatures-of-apks) and show the content of the signing certificate (e.g. the contained name):