# Manual icon change now apk wont install

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, customization

Well I've went into the res folder to spruce up an app icon figuring it would look much better with the modified alternative.

The icon png 's are stored in about five different folders.

`res\drawable-hdpi-v4`

`res\drawable-mdpi-v4`

`res\drawable-xhdpi-v4`

`res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4`

`res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4`

`res\raw`

In each folder there are mainly 3 icon files as png's

`icon.png`

`large_icon.png`

`widget_icon.png`

Of different sizes \large_icon.png being the largest I assume this would be the main app folder icon that displays as the package installer and home screen icon.

I've made changes to the icon that is being used to replace the current one's by copying them over and replacing them with the same file name for each.

The icon being used is the same for each, Around 57kb.

After successfully replacing the icons, rezipping the package and changing the `.zip` to `.apk` the app shows up with the changed icon and will install but when the install is completed a notification comes up saying not installed.

Comment: There's a big possibility that this is caused by JAR signature mismatch [explained on another question](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/9328/44325), preventing the installation.

Comment: @AndrewT., your point is voided by the fact that the app supposedly installs, but doesn't start.

Comment: @ella, could you try using Lucky Patcher's disable APK Signature Verification option to get it to work? (Note: I'm not sure if Lucky Patcher is a safe suggestion, if it isn't for any reason, please feel free to ignore this comment)

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury point taken. "*preventing the installation*" is my comment, not from the link. But still, the link gives hint about signature mismatch, which *could* be the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what the problem is. After editing an apk it needs to be resigned to instal properly. Resigned it with zipsigner as auto-testkey, install error is gone now.