# Does verifying the apk signature fingerprint guarantees it has no malware?

Tags: apk, malware

I want to check if an apk file is really from a specific developer and that the whole apk has no malware in it.

I unzipped the apk and in the sub-folder META/INF I used the following command in Ubuntu:

```
keytool -printcert -file RELEASE_.DSA
```

If I use this technique with a "clean.apk" and a "suspicious.apk" file from the same developer and the MD5 / SHA1 are the same ... does this mean that the "suspicious.apk" really is "clean" ?

Does this work like GnuPG verifying a file? Or is this not reliable to check for integrity / authencity of an apk file?

Comment: I don't understand this concept of "clean" software; unless you've built it yourself, every software is suspect.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9312/how-can-i-verify-the-authenticity-of-an-apk-file-i-downloaded/9328