# Root - patch/change installed application's smali code

Tags: applications, root-access, apk

I want to modify an existing android application, but I want to have it keep its original signature, or at least its capabilities of auto updating and using Google Play services.

I am aware of Lucky Patcher being able to be used to patch the system to disable signature verification, however, there must be another way. Lucky Patcher itself is also capable of patching installed application's code, without invalidating any checks in any way. How is this achieved?

I have also thought of a custom apk installer, ran as root, that just forces the apk install by bypassing the package manager, but I can't find the low-level install process to execute this.

Is there any good solution to modifying an installed Android application and have it still have access to Google Play Services and the like, without patching the Android system?

Comment: not possible, thats what the signature is designed for. installing apk and receiving updates from Google Play are two different things. you can install ANY apk to device (with loosened security settings, no root required)

Comment: @alecxs But Lucky Patcher does it? Do you know what causes Google Play Services to work or not work for an application then?

Comment: Google Play Store (not related to Google Play Services) identifies apps by it's signatures. the signing requires certificate (only author have it) and can therefore not be spoofed. I don't think that Lucky Patcher does recompile apks with it's original signature, i believe this is not possible per design. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218161 Google Play Services is a core component providing all kind of APIs to give apps availbility to interact with android. if it does not work for an application, the app is outdated and needs maintenance from developer