# copy play services from one device to another

Tags: adb, apk, google-play-services

I have an Android device (fire tablet) without playstore/playservices. By googling, I found tons of howtos to download and install the 4 necessary apk packages. Since I have several "offcial google" devices, I thought if it isn't possible to just download the apks from one of them, so I don't have to read a lot to find our which download source is trustable.

While I know how to list all installed packages and also how to `adb pull` them, I only found

- `com.google.android.gsf`
- `com.google.android.gms`
- `com.android.vending`
  but not `com.google.android.gsf.login` in the list retured by `pm list packages`.

Is this package somehow protected and hidden or where could I find it?

Comment: Google play service requires system permissions which means it can not be installed like an app. You need to install it as system app in recovery which requires a device with unlocked bootloader. In that case you can simply use a package from OpenGApps.org to install all Google apps and services you want.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the device is a fire tablet. According to the web, it is possible to just install the .apks downloaded from somewhere. I wanted to give it a try using my already existing ones from my trusted phones, but can't find the .login apk. :(

Comment: In my opinion it would make more sense to strictly following the tutorial you have and download the APK files (especially as the tutorials I have seen require certain versions of the APKs to be installed, not the latest version) . Before installing them you can verify their authenticity by comparing the signature certificate hash of one Google Playstore APK from your device and the hashes from the downloaded files. How to do so is explained [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218161/2241).

Comment: Checking the certificate is a very good idea, I think I will go this way. Thank you for the suggestion. Still wondering that I don't find this one apk on my devices, it seems to be quite special.