# Can I Install the Newer Samsung DeX Version on a Galaxy Note 8 SM-N950F?

Tags: adb, installation, apk, samsung-galaxy-note-8, samsung-dex

I own a Samsung Galaxy Note 8 (SM-N950F) and am interested in utilizing Samsung DeX to connect my phone to a [Windows PC](https://www.samsung.com/global/download/SamsungDeXWin/) via USB-C, leveraging the newer DeX features that allow for a more integrated experience compared to the [original DeX Docking Station](https://www.amazon.nl/Samsung-Dex-oplader-16GB-zwart/dp/B06XY2S68T?source=ps-sl-shoppingads-lpcontext&ref_=fplfs&smid=A14VOEGA849JP5&th=1). I understand that the newer generation of DeX offers additional functionalities, and I'm keen on exploring how I can benefit from these on my device.

After conducting [some research](https://xdaforums.com/t/my-dex-died-after-adb-bloatware-removal.4350107/post-85812849), I found that the following packages are essential for DeX functionality, and most of them are already installed on my phone:

- com.sec.android.desktopmode.uiservice
- com.samsung.desktopsystemui
- com.sec.android.app.desktoplauncher
- com.sec.android.app.dexonpc

The last package (com.sec.android.app.dexonpc) appears to be what I need to enable the newer DeX features. I attempted to install it using an APK from [APKMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/samsung-electronics-co-ltd/dex-for-pc/dex-for-pc-2-4-01-14-release/dex-for-pc-2-4-01-14-android-apk-download/) through `adb install <path\to\file>.apk`, but encountered the error:

```
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install <file>.apk: Failure [-3001]
```

As mentioned in a [Stack Overflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51434560/4999991), I've also tried several commands to address installation issues, but none have succeeded.

My questions are:

1. Is installing the newer version of Samsung DeX on a Galaxy Note 8 feasible, or is this endeavor a dead end due to hardware/software limitations?
2. How safe is it to download and install APKs from third-party websites like APKMirror or APKCombo for this purpose?

I appreciate any insights or experiences you can share regarding upgrading DeX on older Samsung devices.

Comment: My guess is that the DeX components are system apps and this can not be installed by a user without root permissions. regarding the trustworthy of APKs from third party sites: if you have a known original app from the manufacturer (in this case Samsung)  you can extract the APK form your device and check if it uses the same signer certificate hash as the one you have downloaded from the third party site. How to get the signer certificate hash is described e.g. in [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218161/2241).

Comment: Thank @Robert , for the comment. What do you think about the Hades Rom? [This comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyS8/comments/ro7d6t/comment/hpwnfqx/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) says that the newer DeX should work.

Comment: Sorry, never heard before of "Hades Rom". Just like any other custom ROM it may work or not or something in between.