What does the package called "com.example.rftuner" do?
What does the package "com.example.rftuner" do?
It is commonly found in "debloat" lists on the Internet, but I haven't found its actual use.

Do you have a device that contains com.example.rftuner? If yes I would recommend to download it from device and check the APK signature. The signature often contains the developer name. Also decompiling it using Jadx-Gui or apktool allows you to check the strings which are often a good indicator what the app is supposed to do.

@Robert regarding checking the signature in-depth, perhaps you can answer the question How to see the developer of an app?

@AndrewT. I already had written such answer that also displays the developer certificate, but on a different question: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218161/2241
